# How to use a gulp plugin inside a gulp plugin?

Tags: gulp

I want to reuse `gulp-header` plugin inside of my own plugin. How do I do that?

Somewhere inside my plugin I want to do the following:

```
if (file.isBuffer()) {

    /* calculating str */

    file.pipe(header("${str}", {str: str}));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
if (file.isBuffer()) {

    /* calculating str... */

    var headerStream = header("${str}", {str: str});

    headerStream.once('data', function(newFile) {
        file.contents = newFile.contents;
    })

    headerStream.write(file);

}
```